# Database design best practices - linking/junction table with multiple references

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have membership and person tables linked together with membership_person linking table in many-to-many relationship (columns: person_id and membership_id)

Each person can have one or more address, phone and email. These are stored in separate tables eg address, phone and email tables.

The new scenario I am facing now is where a person that has multiple memberships but he/she prefers to use different address, phone number and email for each membership.

Here is an example:

```
M1 => P1 
   => address-1 
   => phone-1 
   => Email-1

M2 => P1 
   => address-2 
   => phone-2 
   => Email-2

M3 => P1 
   => address-3 
   => phone-3 
   => Email-3
```

What is the database best practice to deal with the above? should I create a separate linking tables eg membership_address, membership_phone and membership_email? or just add address_id, phone_id, email_id to the existing membership_person table?

Thanks :)

Comment: You say an address is tied to a membership, not a person.  You have a many to many relationship between person and membership, and a one to one relationship between membership and address.

Comment: Can multiple people have the same membership? If not, the membership_person linking table seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yes Mark, a person can have 0 or more memberships and a membership can have one or more persons.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, it could also be many to many between membership and address. see comments in the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *association data* - data about the association between two entities - and you store it on the association table.

Something like (using mysql syntax):

```
create table membership_person (
    person_id int not null references person,
    membership_id int not null references membership,
    address_id int not null references address,
    phone_id int not null references phone,
    email_id int not null references email,
    primary key (person_id, membership_id)
)
```

The extra 3 columns define the contact entity for a person *for each membership*.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply Bohemian. I suggested the same solution to the team this morning but the argument was whether or not this is normalized. It looks perfectly fine to me except for a situation where a user want to have 2 preferred addresses instead of one. This will obviously require adding another address_id to the table. Or what do you think?

Comment: yes - add another column for secondary address. Also, you can still have referential integrity that requires the address referred to in the association table to belong to the person in that row by defining a two-column foreign key constraint: `foreign key (person_id, address_id) references address(person_id, address_id)`

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, this should resolve the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending, below is a suggestion.

**Table**: Membership_Person

**Compound Primary Key** (membership_id, person_id, table_id, priority)

**Fields**:

- *membership_id* - references the membership table
- *person_id* - references the person table
- *table_id* - indicates either the phone, address, or email table as the referenced table for this row
- *table_entry_id* - primary key for the referenced table
- *priority* - the preferred entry for this person + membership + (phone,
  address, or email)